# SQLite Trigger for Inserting values from different tables

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I would like to create a trigger on SQLite to update one table with values from more than one table. I have tried the code below but navicat for Sqlite wont save my trigger. Could someone help?

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO hdClassSet (setNo, class, type, regdate, acYear)
      VALUES (((SELECT max(setNo) FROM hdClassSet)+1), 
              old.clID,
              0,  
              (date('now','localtime')),
              (SELECT acID FROM tblAcad WHERE actv1=1));
END
```

I managed to save and test the trigger without the last value and it works. How can I reference another table that does not start or affected by the trigger? I will be grateful!

Comment: Have you consulted the SQLite documentation?

Comment: That code is not a complete trigger. And why are you keeping the database schema and the error message a secret?

Comment: @CL - am using navicat as mentioned above... When I try to save the above code, there is no error returned.. both the last field and the value are removed and the rest are saved. How does a complete trigger look like?

Comment: [documentation: CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)